Unhiding Parent and Children Sheets and move to Right of Index Sheet
I am calling the Parent sheet with the Listbox, and the Parent Sheet should be moved to the right of the "Index" Sheet, and then the Case Statement with the Array Sheets, which are the Children sheets should be set to visible, and nestled to the right of the Parent Sheet. It sounds good in theory, and I've learned to stay away from worksheet activation coding with vis and non vis because it does the error runaway-train thing.
I'm getting an error on the targetSheetName Variable Not Set.'For Each targetSheetName In targetSheetNames'.
Sub CaseArray()
        Dim wsIndex As Worksheet
        Dim selectedItem As String
        Dim targetSheetNames As Variant
        Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
        Dim lastMovedSheet As Worksheet
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
        Set wsIndex = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Index")
    
        selectedItem = ListBox2.Value
    
        Select Case selectedItem
            Case "LXXXXXXB"
                targetSheetNames = Array("LxxxxxxB-LxxxxxxT", "LxxxxxxB-LxxxxxxO", "LxxxxxxB-BxxxxxxO")
            Case "LXXXXXXT"
                targetSheetNames = Array("LxxxxxxT-LxxxxxxO","LxxxxxxV-LxxxxxxO")
            Case "LxxxxxxO"
                targetSheetNames = Array("LxxxxxxO-LxxxxxxT", "LxxxxxxO-BxxxxxxO")

            Case Else
                MsgBox "Invalid selection.", vbInformation
                Exit Sub
        End Select
    
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Next ws
    
        For Each targetSheetName In targetSheetNames
        Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(targetSheetName)
        Debug.Print "targetSheetName: " & targetSheetName
    
            targetSheet.Move After:=lastMovedSheet
            Set lastMovedSheet = targetSheet
        Next targetSheetName
    
            Worksheets(selectedItem).Activate
    
    End Sub


        Sub CaseArray3()
    
        Dim wsIndex As Worksheet
        Dim ParentSheetName As String
        'Dim ChildArray As Variant
        Dim targetSheetNames As Variant
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim idx As Long, i As Long
        Dim selectedItem As String
        
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
        Set wsIndex = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Index")
        
        ParentSheetName = ListBox2.Value
        selectedItem = ListBox2.Value ' Assuming ListBox1 is where the selection is made
        
        Select Case selectedItem

            Case "NLXXXX61"
                targetSheetNames = Array("NLXXXX61-NLXXXXAV", "NLXXXX61-JCXXXXCX")
            Case "JCXXXXCX"
                targetSheetNames = Array("JCXXXXCX-NLXXXX61", "JCXXXXCX-NLXXXXEP")
            Case "NLXXXXEP"
                targetSheetNames = Array("NLXXXXEP-LTXXXXTB", "NLXXXX61-JCXXXXCX")
            Case Else
                MsgBox "Invalid selection.", vbInformation
                Exit Sub
        End Select
        
        idx = wsIndex.Index
        With Worksheets(ParentSheetName)
            .Visible = True
            .Move After:=Worksheets(idx)
        End With
        
        For i = 0 To UBound(targetSheetNames)
        
            idx = idx + 1
            With Worksheets(targetSheetNames(i))
            .Visible = True
            .Move After:=Worksheets(idx)
            
            End With
            
        Next i
    
    End Sub


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
